# How to open a word doc, enter data & save as PDF in React JS

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf

```
let filename = "document.doc";
let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = "data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
downloadLink.download = filename;
downloadLink.click();
```

Currently we are using above code to create a .doc file with data

But we want to save this file as .pdf using React JS

When we replace the filename with `filename.pdf` it is showing error as

```
Failed to load PDF document
```

Comment: _"When we replace the filename with 'filename.pdf' it is showing error as "Failed to load PDF document""_ - May I ask what made you think simply renaming the file extension would work?

Comment: You'll need to convert the doc to PDF after saving it... Good luck